# GetMethod returning null c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection

I don't understand why `GetMethod` return `null` - two times at `method1` and `method`

```
Type model = AssemblyHelper.GetTypeByClassName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), modelName + MappingColums.Tokens.Validation); // MappingColums.Tokens.Validation = "Validation"
```

for testing purpose I try get method twice:

```
MethodInfo method1 = model.GetType().GetMethod(MappingColums.Tokens.Get + modelName); // MappingColums.Tokens.Get + modelName = "Get" + "Product"
MethodInfo method = model.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == MappingColums.Tokens.Get + modelName && x.GetParameters().Count() == 0);
object result = method.Invoke(model, null);
```

below class and method that I want to use by reflection.

```
public class ProductValidation
{
    private IProductRepository repositoryProduct;

    public ProductValidation(IProductRepository repoProduct)
    {
        repositoryProduct = repoProduct;
    }

    public ICollection<Product> GetProduct()
    {
        return repositoryProduct.Products.ToList();
    }

}
```

I do not know if it matters, but I'm using `ASP.NET Core MVC`. Where I debug `Type model` just behind `AssemblyHelper.GetTypeByClassName` there is at `Declared Methods:  {System.Collections.Generic.ICollection1[AureliaCMS.Models.Entities.Product] GetProduct()}`

Please give me advice where to look up for issue.

**EDIT:**
Thank you very much - you both were right - `Klaus Gütter` and `Aldert`

**working code**

```
    public static class AssemblyHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Type> GetLoadableTypes(Assembly assembly)
        {
            if (assembly == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(assembly));
            try
            {
                return assembly.GetTypes();
            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
            {
                return e.Types.Where(t => t != null);
            }
        }
        public static Type GetTypeByClassName(Assembly assembly, string className)
        {
            if (assembly == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(assembly));
            return AssemblyHelper.GetLoadableTypes(assembly).Where(a => a.Name == className).FirstOrDefault();
        }
}

Type model = AssemblyHelper.GetTypeByClassName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), MappingColums.Tokens.EF + modelName + MappingColums.Tokens.Repository);
MethodInfo method = model.GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == MappingColums.Tokens.Get + modelName + MappingColums.Tokens.Validation && x.GetParameters().Count() == 0);
ConstructorInfo constructor = model.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(AureliaCMSStoreContext) });
object instanceConstructor = constructor.Invoke(new object[] { context });
object instanceMethod = method.Invoke(instanceConstructor, null);
```

Comment: Since `model` is already the desired type, remove the `GetType()`, i.e. write `model.GetMethod(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will never work. You need an instance of your object to execute the method on. Something like:

```
    Type model = AssemblyHelper.GetTypeByClassName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), modelName + MappingColums.Tokens.Validation);

    MethodInfo method = model.GetMethod(MappingColums.Tokens.Get + modelName);

    myClass myObject = new myObject();

    object result = method.Invoke(myObject , null);
```